# How to I get the error stack trace to appera in my JBoss server log?

Tags: spring, logging, jboss, wildfly, stack-trace

I have a Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE running on Wildfly 10.  On a particular page of my application, this is being printed to my browser

```
{"status":"failure","exception":"ClassCastException","exceptionMessage":"java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.List","errorMessage":"java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.List"}
```

I would like to figure out what the stack trace of what is causing this, but it is not listed in my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log/server.log file.  How do I make it appear?  Below is my logging configuration in my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file …

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

I have defined no log4j.proeprties or log4j.xml in my application so I’m not sure how else to configure getting a stack trace to appear in my logs.

Comment: Remove logging jars from your deployment.

Comment: Is there any message being logged from the application?